# Tomcat Virtual host Requests for different wars

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

What are the best practices for handling multiple host requests with same context path :eg: "my-services" for different environment(Test, Dev, Prod) from a Tomcat 7 server
I want my webapplication with different flavors of war, say test.war, dev.war to be deployed on the same tomcat instance. Please let me know what are the caveats in doing this? This war file is Restful web service which will be consumed by a different Apache HTTPD server running on the same machine as that of my tomcat server.

Comment: I would never deploy anything alongside prod. You risk destabilizing your production application with whatever you are doing in dev/test.

Comment: Yeah neither do I , I just want to separate dev and QA environment :)

Comment: Do they absolutely need to be differentiated by the hostname? What about a different context name (i.e. URL prefix)? You can do separate context names without changing any configuration at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example. Also I need two different virtual hosts and context name

Comment: Is it acceptable to have `www.host.com/dev` and `www.host.com/qa`? It will be a lot easier to configure.

Comment: I was able to use virtual hosts on my Local machine, following the tomcat documentatin, I was missing one of the env configuration which I configured later/\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Tomcat documentation but the following links explain it in more elaborative manner

http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/tomcat-vhost.html?bcsi-ac-0f50f852aecff21e=24AEDC5100000002vjkkrulW4BXxZrg4kowoM6tbvxodBAAAAgAAACtxDwAsAQAAAAAAACMXAgA=

Comment: If you explain what the confusion was, we can update the Tomcat documentation to make it more clear. You can even post comments in the Tomcat documentation with suggestions for how to clarify the docs. Or file a Bugzilla bug against the documentation.

Comment: Also please note that the link you provided is out-of-date with respect to the current state-of-the-art. There are some actual bad practices (e.g. specifying a `path` in the `<Context>`) and some unnecessary steps (e.g. putting an otherwise empty `web.xml` into the web-app) in there.